# How can I know how long it takes to run updatedb daily job?

Tags: updatedb

I'm using CentOS6.4 and `updatedb` is running as a daily job.
What should I do if I want to know how long it takes for `updatedb` to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `time` bash builtin. Consider this example and modify the `cron` job accordingly:

```
$ time ( ls -lrt &>/dev/null )

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s
```

You can also redirect the output somewhere else:

```
time ( $CRON_JOB_CODE ) &> /var/log/updatedb.time.log
```